# Is my Chrome extension code correct (Google rejected it but it works locally)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've made a Chrome extension that works perfectly fine in dev mode but was rejected for the following reasons:

> - Violation:
>
>   - The package contains “MyExt.crx” file which is not a valid file
>   - The “news.js” and other files mentioned in the manifest are not available in the package which is throwing an error while
>     installing.
> - How to rectify: Please package your extension properly and re-submit on the developer dashboard.
> - Additional Information: Permissions usage was not validated as the js files are not available in the package

I wonder if I misunderstood how it's supposed to work and wrongly used content_scripts.

Btw, yes, I did the tutorial and I read the documentation (more than once).

First of all, here is my project, pretty simple:

[image]

My popup (when you click the extension) has several checkboxes that store and load their state through `chrome.storage.sync.set` and `chrome.storage.sync.get`.

The files `news.js` and `blocks.js` change the DOM of the website, depending on the checkboxes.

Here is my manifest:

```
{
"manifest_version": 3,
"name": "MyExtension",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Blabla",
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://www.randomsite.com/*"],
        "js": ["news.js", "blocks.js"]
    }
],
"permissions": ["storage"],
"action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
        "16": "/images/logo16.png",
        "32": "/images/logo32.png",
        "48": "/images/logo48.png",
        "128": "/images/logo128.png"
    }
},
"icons": {
    "16": "/images/logo16.png",
    "32": "/images/logo32.png",
    "48": "/images/logo48.png",
    "128": "/images/logo128.png"
}
}
```

What I wanted to do is the extension to work on randomsite.com only.

I don't understand what is wrong here, does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Sounds like you uploaded a crx file inside zip, which is wrong. Simply pack the contents of your extension's directory into a zip file and upload it to the web store, no crx is necessary.

Comment: @wOxxOm I indeed packed it like that, crx + manifest in a zip! I'm pretty sure I read that somewhere, oh gosh. Thanks.

Comment: I confirm that was the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As wOxxOm commented, the problem was the ZIP I submitted. I read somewhere I had to submit the CRX file in a ZIP, but it's not the case. The ZIP must contain the folders and files of the project. The official documentation explains this right: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/hosting/